# Error # 9233. Command name: GET FILE

Tags: dataset, spss

I'm a student who gets SPSS for free from my university, so IBM's customer support has been completely useless. I keep getting the following error on my Mac:

> GET
>
> FILE='/Users/~my name~/Downloads/usnews 1995 college data.sav'.
>
> >Error # 9233.  Command name: GET FILE
>
> >The procedure could not be executed because a required external module was
>
> >either not readable or corrupt.
>
> >Execution of this command stops.
>
> dlopen errno(2): No such file or directory
>
> dlopen(/Applications/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/21/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/bin/../lib/libspsswfil
>
> .dylib, 10): Symbol not found: __ZN14SpssGoToCallerD1Ev
>
> Referenced from: /Applications/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/21/SPSSSt
>
> DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? I tried uninstalling and doing a fresh installation and changing the data set file names to exclude special characters. No improvement. I can also open output files just fine, but I can't view the corresponding data files at all.

Answer (score 0):

See this link for technical support for students
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14941991&#14941991

I have not heard of this problem before - it does sound like a corrupted installation, but TS will want to know exactly what version of Statistics and exactly what Mac OS version you are using.